# How to let server send the message first in GRPC using python

Tags: python, grpc

Hi i am new to GRPC and i want to send one message from server to client first. I understood how to implement client sending a message and getting response from server. But i wanna try how server could initiate a message to connected clients. How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: you can't**

gRPC is a request-response framework based on HTTP2. Just as you cannot make a website that initiates a connection to a browser, you cannot make a gRPC service initiating a connection to the client. How would the service even know who to talk to?

A solution could be to open a gRPC server on the client. This way both the client and the server can accept connections from one another.